# Is it possible to open multiple ports on one program?

Tags: sockets, bots, ports

I am programming a bot that would emulate different users on one site. If all on the same port I wouldn't know a way to identify which virtual user should receive a data packet. I thought about opening multiple ports on one program, googled it, but I couldn't find information. Is it possible?

Comment: indeed possible . why should it be restricted ?

Comment: What platform/language are you using? You need to remember that the destination port is separate from the source port, normally allocated automatically.

Comment: @CyprUS Don't know, just didn't find info about it.

Comment: @Lazarus C++, I know that destination port would always be the same :80. Also, I would need a program to know to which port packet was sent to.

Comment: @VanillaFace The packet would be sent to the destination port and responses returned to the source port, each source port should be different, that's how you differentiate each 'session'. I'm not sure what you are struggling with, it's very straight forward. Open a connection for each virtual user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can open multiple sockets, each listening on a different port.

The question is, do you need it?

> If all on the same port I wouldn't know a way to identify which virtual user should receive a data packet.

You can build this into the protocol, for example a message consist of first the identifier of the user (fixed number of bytes), then the size of the message (eg: stored with an int32_t) and then the actual message.

Comment: Now, that you mentioned it, I've analyzed packets. It appears the send cookie and receive cookie is unchanged, so, I guess this question from me was pointless apart that I found out that cookies aren't changed.